# Finite index subgroup with free abelianization

Tags: gr.group-theory, nilpotent-groups

This question has been asked on MathExchange to no avail.

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated nilpotent group with abelianization of rank $r$. Does $G$ always have a subgroup $H$ of finite index, such that $H$ abelianized is a free abelian group of rank $r$?

Since this is MathOverflow, I will push the question further - under what conditions can we expect abelianization of a monic map to be monic?

Comment: So the subgroup H would have to be simple non-abelian, and it can't because it's nilpotent? You're right, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Geoff: I believe rank here means the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ summands, i.e., the Betti number.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for clearing that up


Comment: I'll just add the link to [math.se]: [Finite index subgroup with free abelianization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59571) (as [recommended](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Warning:** (YCor) the following argument is mistaken as was pointed out by Derek Holt: the assertion that the abelianization of a torsion-free nilpotent group is torsion-free is hopelessly wrong.

---

The answer is "yes" because every f.g. nilpotent group has a torsion-free finite index subgroup and because the abelianization of a torsion-free nilpotent group is torsion-free. I assume that by "rank" you meant the torsion-free (${\mathbb Q}$-)rank.

Comment: I love the answer, but could you give a sketch of proof or at least a reference?

Comment: Finite index torsion-free follows from the fact the torsion subgroup of your G is finite, and G is residually finite. I don't know why the abelianization must be torsion free.

Comment: The first statement follows trivially from the fact that nilpotent groups are linear. It also trivially follows from Theorem 16.2.7 in Kargapolov-Merzlyakov and the fact that f.g. nilpotent groups are residually finite. The second is Exercise 16.2.10 in Kargapolov-Merzlyakov. 

Comment: @Mark: take a look at exercise 16.2.11 in the same book!

Comment: Steve: Oops! I mixed two series. Still the result should be true, but it requires a different proof. 

Comment: To be specific, the group $\langle a,b,c \mid ac=ca, bc=cb, ba=abc^2 \rangle$ is torsion-free nilpotent, but its abelianization has is $\mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 9):

This seems surprisingly difficult! Let's try and do it by induction on the nilpotency class of $G$. The result is clear for abelian groups.

Let $Z$ be the last nontrivial subgroup in the lower central series of $G$. So $Z \le G' \cap Z(G)$. By induction, $G$ has a finite index normal subgroup $H$ containing $Z$ such that the abelianization $H/ZH'$ of $H/Z$ is free abelian.

Since $G$ is nilpotent, $|G:H|$ finite implies $|G':H'|$ finite. So $|Z:Z \cap H'| = |H'Z:H'|$ is finite, and $H'Z/H'$ has a free abelian normal complement $K/H'$ in $H/H'$ with $|H:K|$ finite.

But $H = KZ$ and  $Z$ is central imply $K' = H'$, and hence $K/K' = K/H'$ is free abelian.

Comment: Does $[G:H]$ finite implying $[G':H']$ finite hold, even if $G$ is not torsion-free?

Comment: Steve: yes. The torsion subgroup is unimportant because it is finite and can be factored out. The statement is equivalent to a (f.g.) virtually abelian nilpotent group has finite derived group. You could could prove that by induction on the finite bit at the top, and reduce to the case of an extension of a free abelian group by a cyclic group of prime order.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Could you please elaborate why $[G:H]$ finite implies $[G':H']$ finite when $G$ is nilpotent?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative proof (at least, an alternative wording), making $H$ very explicit.

For $r$ the rank, let $G\to\mathbf{Z}^r$ be a surjective homomorphism (e.g., take the abelianization homomorphism and mod out by the torsion subgroup). Lift the $r$ generators to $r$ elements of $G$: they generate a subgroup $H$. So $H$ is generated by $r$ elements, and surjects onto $\mathbf{Z}^r$, and hence the abelianization of $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^r$.

To conclude, we need to check that $H$ has finite index in $G$. For this I claim more generally that

> *if $G$ is a nilpotent group and $H$ is a subgroup such that $H[G,G]$ has finite index in $G$, then $H$ has finite index in $G$.*

If $G$ is abelian the result is trivial. Otherwise, let $G^k$ be the last nontrivial term in the lower central series, so $G^k$ is central and contained in $[G,G]$. By induction on the nilpotency class, we obtain that $G^kH$ has finite index. The $k$-fold commutator map induces a surjective homomorphism $\Lambda^kG_{\mathrm{ab}}\to G^k$. By an easy argument, the finite index inclusion $H\to G$ induces a homomorphism $\Lambda^kH_{\mathrm{ab}}\to \Lambda^kG_{\mathrm{ab}}$ whose image has finite index. Hence the image of $\Lambda^kH_{\mathrm{ab}}$ in $G^k$ has finite index in $G^k$. This image is precisely $H^k$. Hence the inclusion $H\subset G^kH$ has finite index. Since we obtained that $G^kH$ has finite index in $G$, we conclude that $H$ has finite index.

[Actually this argument through $\Lambda^k$, maybe suitably rephrased, is needed to prove the fact asserted by Derek that a finite index inclusion of nilpotent groups induces a finite index inclusion of the derived subgroups. It's true for all terms of the lower central series, and in a sense the most basis step is that of the last term (done above), where things can be linearized.]

PS. A better version of all this would be to control the index of $H$ in terms of the size of the torsion subgroup of $[G,G]$, and the Hirsch length of $G$ (or, more optimistically, the size of the torsion subgroup of $G$ and the nilpotency class of $G$ modulo its torsion subgroup).